# How would you add spaces in front of every capital letter in a macro string, in SAS?

Tags: string, sas

I have several macro variables like this:

```
%let name=MyCamelisedString;
```

And I'm searching for a formula to automatically add spaces in front of every capital letter (except the first one but that I can correct myself).

In order to obtain:

> My Camelised String

My current idea is to go with [ANYUPPER()](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002194376.htm)  function but that would require a loop which would be nice to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple regular expression to do this, although the macro syntax is a bit cumbersome:

```
%let name=MyCamelisedString;

%let regex = %sysfunc(prxparse(s/([A-Z])/ $1/));

%let name2 = %sysfunc(prxchange(&regex, -1, &name));

%put &name2;
```

If you want to avoid putting spaces in front of consecutive caps except for the last one then you need a somewhat more complicated regex:

```
%let name=MyCamelisedStringCAPSWORDProperword;

%let regex2 = %sysfunc(prxparse(s/((?<![A-Z])[A-Z]|[A-Z][a-z])/ $1/));
%let name2 = %sysfunc(prxchange(&regex2, -1, &name));
```

This has two match conditions:

1. `(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]` matches any capital letter that doesn't have another capital letter in front of it. This is a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).
2. `[A-Z][a-z]` matches any capital letter that has a lowercase letter after it.

If you just use `([A-Z][a-z])` as suggested by stallingOne, this won't match the start of an all caps word, and the output for the sample string above is `My Camelised StringCAPSWORD Properword`.

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to not split if the capital letter is followed by another capital? Like `HACCPProcessingSize` should become `HACCP Processing Size`

Comment: I think I found it:  %sysfunc(prxparse(s/([A-Z][a-z])/ $1/));